# Unexpected newlines being printed in Python

Tags: python

Trying to figure out why these unexpected newlines are being printed in a simple script. All I want to do in this script is read in a file, and print the contents of each line.

The code is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

# This script should just iterate over a file and echo the contents of each line

f=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
for line in f:
  line.rstrip('\n')
  print "Line 1 is: " + line
f.close()
```

The input file is just 2 lines:

```
#cat users 
root
dontexist
#
```

When I run the script with this input file, there are extra newlines in the output:

```
#./test.py users
Line 1 is: root

Line 1 is: dontexist

#
```

What am I missing? Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rstrip and similar functions (e.g. replace, strip, etc.) return a copy with the changed string as opposed to changing the string in place.  You want to do `line = line.rstrip("\n")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do :

```
line = line.rstrip('\n')
```

Currently you don't make change to the variable "line"